# Directory.GetDirectories throwing exception

Tags: c#, path

In the below code I have two variable one is `currentDirectoryPath` and the other is `rootPath`. I want to enumerate all the subfolders in these two root paths using `Directory.GetDirectories()` function. But when I pass `currentDirectoryPath` the code is *working fine* but **not with the** `rootPath.`
I have an **exception thrown**:

> NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.

I have tested the code with the two paths:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace ConsoleApp
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               string currentDirectoryPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
               string rootPath = "‪C:\\Users\\Ravi.Reddy\\Desktop\\Practise";

               string[] dirs1 = Directory.GetDirectories(
                   currentDirectoryPath, 
                  "*.*", 
                   SearchOption.AllDirectories);

              foreach (var dir in dirs1)
                  Console.WriteLine(dir);

              string[] dirs2 = Directory.GetDirectories( // <- Exception here
                  rootPath, 
                 "*.*",
                  SearchOption.AllDirectories);

              foreach (var dir in dirs2)
                  Console.WriteLine(dir);

              Console.ReadLine();
           }
      }
 }
```

I expect `Directory.GetDirectories()` should work with the provided path and it should enumerate all the subfolders.

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: Why C#-2.0, C#-3.0, C#-4.0 and C#?

Answer (score 4):

You have an *incorrect* `rootPath`, just have a look at the *damp*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // Copy + Paste from the question
  string rootPath = "‪C:\\Users\\Ravi.Reddy\\Desktop\\Practise";

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    rootPath.Select(c => $"\\u{(int)c:x4} : {c}")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
\u202a : ‪
\u0043 : C
\u003a : :
\u005c : \
\u0055 : U
\u0073 : s
\u0065 : e
\u0072 : r
\u0073 : s
 ...
```

Please, note `\u202a` charcode ([LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm)) It must not appear in a valid path. All you have to do is to *retype* `"‪C:` fragment in order to get rid of *invisible* LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING symbol.